Python3 alphanumeric sorting of filenames
in python3 how would I sort myList into the desiredOrder:
myList = ['2', '3', '10', '4c', '4d', '4a', '4b', '5', '6', '6a', '6d', '6b', '6c', '6e', '6f', '7', '8']

desiredOrder = ['2', '3', '4a', '4b', '4c', '4d', '5', '6', '6a', '6b', '6c', '6d', '6e', '6f', '7', '8', '10']

without prior knowledge of desiredOrder
